# React Redux dispatch an action to another domain for authentication

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm using the omniauth-github strategy and upon a button click I want to dispatch an action to another domain, (such as 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize'). When using dispatch this however does not work as the browser preflights my request and resonds with 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. I can get this to work by using an  and point to the url, which then will send the user back to my backend to authenticate the user get the token store it. But without dispatch, I have to send back the JWT token my site generates in query params, and since I am omitting my action creators and reducers, I cannot store it in localStorage. Is there any way to perform dispatch cross domain?

```
export const loginGitHub = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch('https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=...&scope=user',{
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      mode: 'cors'
    })
    .then(resp=>resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      debugger
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide your redux store's `dispatch` method to this method for it to work, this is typically done by using `mapDispatchToProps` with redux's `connect()` method: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

That's the typical flow, if for some reason you need to call this outside a component like before you mount your React app (but after you've initialized your redux store) something like this can work:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const store = createStore();

export const loginGitHub = dispatch => {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch('https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=...&scope=user',{
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      mode: 'cors'
    })
    .then(resp=>resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      debugger
    })
  }
}

loginGitHub(store.dispatch);
```

That's very much an anti pattern, and I'd recommend properly using `mapDispatchToProps` which requires

Creating a store
Wrapping your app in a provider and providing the previously created store as a prop to the provider.
Using `connect()` like so within your component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'redux';

import { loginGitHub } from './wherever';

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  // whatever component methods you need
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  loginGitHub: () => dispatch(logInGitHub())
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ExampleComponent);
```

Then you'll be able to call loginGitHub with `this.props.loginGitHub()` within your component.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, very thorough. I have all of that wired up in my container, where the method gets dispatched via this.props.loginGItHub(), the request is actually sent out and in my catch I see it come back as an error. My dev tools network tab displays the request being made but returns with the above referenced error “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin”

Comment: @O.MeeKoh ahh. I looked up specifically this GitHub flow. They want you to send the user to them, the user approves the requests, then the user gets redirected back to you? You can save a partially completed sign up form for example in localStorage and retrieve it when the user comes back, snatch the auth token from the uri Parma’s and initialize your store with the needed data, detect that it’s all there, and then submit the needed info to complete sign up or log in?

Comment: Yes exactly! So the problem I am having is initially sending them to github. Dispatch will not allow me to redirect them to github to initially log in and authorize. Strangely <a href> works, and so does executing client side javascript as soon as my github button component is clicked.